# Class constructor not sending data DATA to VBO

Tags: opengl, constructor, vbo, glew

I have a class named Model, that handles all information needed to draw itself. Basically it has 2 methods:

1) Contructor - Create and Initilizes VBO, VAO and uniform staff.
2) Draw - Bind VAO and Draw

My problem is that initializing VBO using glBufferData. I´ve noticed the data that was supposed to be uploaded to GPU memory is not that!! I did check this using gDebugger. Also observed that if i try to send the data again outside and after contructor class, everything goes ok. What am i missing???

The class instanced object of Model is a global variable, having template parameter V and M as vec4 and mat4 respectively.

I have also tested on linux/Windows/NVIDIA/RADEON and same behavior happens. Using #verson 400 for Shaders and glew, glm math library.

Here goes the code:

1) Constructor:

```
/** This constructor has 5 steps:
 *  1) Allocate variables
 *  2) Create, bind and Send vbo inf.
 *  3) Create, bind vao info
 *  4) Create mapping between Buffer and Attributes in GPU memory
 *  5) Get uniform variables location
 * 
 * */
template<class V, class M>
Model<V, M>::Model( GLuint size, GLuint program ){
    assert( size > 0 );

    /** BEG - 1) Allocate variables */
    /** beg - model variable initialization */
    this->vertex        = new vec4[ size ];
    this->numVertex     = size;

    this->color         = new vec4[ size ];
    this->numColor      = size;

    //this->element     => not initialized
    //this->numElem     => not initialized

    this->modelMatrix   = M(1); // Identity Matrix
    this->position      = V(0); // Orign

    // VBO - Vertex Buffer Object information
    this->vbo           = new GLuint[ this->numBuff ];
    this->vboSize       = this->numBuff;

    // VAO - Vexter Array Object information
    this->vao           = new GLuint[ 1 ];
    this->numVao        = 1;
    this->attrib        = new GLuint[ this->numBuff ];
    this->numAttrib     = this->numBuff;

    this->uniform       = new string[ this->numUni ];
    this->uniformLoc    = new GLuint[ this->numUni ];
    this->numUniform    = this->numUni;

    this->program       = program;

    //beg - Inittialization
    this->attrib[VERTEX]     = 0;
    this->attrib[COLOR]      = 1;

    this->uniform[0]         = string("modelMatrix");
    this->uniform[1]         = string("position");
    //end - Inittialization
    /** END - 1) Allocate variables */


    /** BEG - 2) Create, bind and Send vbo inf */
    // Create vbo identifier
    glGenBuffers( this->vboSize, this->vbo );
    Other<V>::checkError("glGenBuffers");

    // Bind Buffer
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (this->vbo)[0] );
    Other<V>::checkError("glBindBuffer");

    // Send Data to buffer
    glBufferData(   GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( (this->vertex)[0][0] ) * (this->vertex)[0].length() * (this->numVertex),
                    &(this->vertex[0][0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    Other<V>::checkError("glBufferData");

    // Bind Buffer
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (this->vbo)[1] );
    Other<V>::checkError("glBindBuffer");

    // Send Data to buffer
    glBufferData(   GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( (this->color)[0][0] ) * (this->color)[0].length() * (this->numColor),
                    &(this->color[0][0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    Other<V>::checkError("glBufferData");
    /** END - 2) Create, bind and Send vbo inf */


    /** BEG - 3) Create, bind and enable vao info */
    // Create vao identifier
    glGenVertexArrays( 1, this->vao );
    Other<V>::checkError("glGenVertexArrays");
    glBindVertexArray( (this->vao)[0] );
    Other<V>::checkError("glBindVertexArray");

    // Enable attributes
    for ( uint i=0; i<numAttrib; i++ ){
        glEnableVertexAttribArray( i );
        Other<V>::checkError("glEnableVertexAttribArray");
    }
    /** END - 3) Create and enable vao info */


    /** BEG - 4) Create mapping between Buffer and Attributes in GPU memory */
    for ( uint i=0; i<numAttrib; i++ ){
        glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (this->vbo)[i] );
        Other<V>::checkError("glBindBuffer");
        glVertexAttribPointer( (this->attrib)[i], (this->vertex)[i].length(), GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (GLubyte *)NULL);
        Other<V>::checkError("glBindBuffer");
    }
    /** END - 4) Create mapping between Buffer and Attributes in GPU memory */


    /** BEG - 5) Get uniform variables location */
    for ( uint i=0; i<numAttrib; i++ ){
        this->uniformLoc[i] = glGetUniformLocation( program, this->uniform[i].c_str() );
        Other<V>::checkError("glGetUniformLocation");
    }
    /** END - 5) Get uniform variables location */
}
```

2) Draw

```
template<class V, class M>
void Model<V, M>::draw()
{
    //glUniformMatrix4fv( this->uniformLoc[0], 1, GL_FALSE, &(this->modelMatrix[0][0]) );
    //glUniform4fv(       this->uniformLoc[1], 1, &(this->position[0]) );

    glBindVertexArray( (this->vao)[0] );
    glDrawArrays( GL_LINE_STRIP, 0, this->numVertex);
}
```

To "resend" data to GPU after contructor i use the sendData member function:

```
template<class V, class M>
void Model<V, M>::sendData()
{
    glBindBuffer( GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, (this->vbo)[0] );

    // Send Data to buffer
    glBufferData(   GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof( (this->vertex)[0][0] ) * (this->vertex)[0].length() * (this->numVertex),
                        &(this->vertex[0][0]), GL_STATIC_DRAW);
}
```

EDIT: I forgot to add sendData member function

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a valid opengl context setup before the constructor is called (called `glewInit()`)?

If you have any statically defined objects with OpenGL calls they will fail because they are constructed before main(). If you want an object with opengl calls in the constructor you have to be careful to create it with `new` only after the context is initialized.

Comment: Thanks, I did have called glewInit before constructor. I call new  for the object model after all init of glut and glew.
All opengl commands inside constructor are issued after that.

Answer (score 0):

If you instanciate that class anywhere before getting a render context, for example static initializers or similar, then it will not work.

Basically you should never put OpenGL operations into a class constructor, unless you somehow make sure, that it will operator on a valid context. You can do this, by encapsulating a valid OpenGL context in another class' instance and passing that as parameter to constructors operating on the context.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know that, as i told right below, i issue every opengl command, in constructor, only after link stage.

Comment: @LucasRibeiro: What do you understand by "link stage"? Usually "Linking" is understood as the process of merging compilation units into a runnable program.

Comment: Yes, i know. Sorry if i was not clear. Im talking about shader link process.